# ObjectOutputStream writing array to file with inherited classes not writing to file

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, output, objectoutputstream

My assignment is to save a list of employees as a binary file (and later read from it).  I'm working on the output portion now, below is the block of the function that is in question.  This function does have about 10 more lines but they edit things on the TextField arraylist.

The Employee class is the parent of both the Supervisor and Secretary classes.  all is the ArrayList that holds all the employee, secretary, and employee objects.

I'm using netbeans 8.0.2, when the program runs and I click the save button in the gui (onActionEvent() is this function) there are no compiler errors.  The "IO Error" or "No Permissions..." doesn't output.  Ive tried saving both with and without the employees.dat file being already created.

I'm not really sure what to do at this point, I contemplated saving each object as a the collection of int, String, etc but that's dumb, it should be able to work this way... right?

EDIT:
Employee, Supervisor, and Secretary are all Serializable.

```
private void saveChanges(ArrayList<Employee> all, ArrayList<TextField> text, int index) {


    try ( ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("employees.dat", true)); ) {

        for (int i = 0; i < all.size(); i++) {
            if (all.get(i).getClass() == (new Secretary().getClass()))
                output.writeObject(new Secretary((Secretary) all.get(i)));
            else if (all.get(i).getClass() == (new Supervisor().getClass()))
                output.writeObject(new Supervisor((Supervisor) all.get(i)));
            else
                output.writeObject(new Employee(all.get(i)));
        }

        output.flush();
    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I have edited the try-catch to this code...

```
try ( ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("employees.dat", true)); ) {

                output.writeObject(all);


        output.flush();
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Still not writing to file.  I have permissions in the folder the .java files are in.

Comment: Why all the class testing and the 'copy construction'? Just write the objects. In fact, just write the *list.* One line of code. You don't need all this. NB you can't append to files created as object output streams, at least not like that. You'll just have to find an exception and stack trace somewhere, and post them.

Comment: why don't you use "instanceof" instead of checking the class type using == and make sure the object is castes to the correct class type and try explicit type casting before writing the objects try debug and inspect the values once to make sure that the object  casts to the correct destination type.

Comment: @Vigneshearan.m Why do any of it? It's pointless. Just write the objects, or the list.

Comment: I think you are reading multiple object types and casting it while you write it ie "(new Employee(all.get(i)))" instead try output.writeObject(all.get(i)); thats what i guess

Comment: @Vigneshearan.m That's not a cast, it's a constructor.

Comment: @OP You haven't taken *all* my advice. Please do. Get rid of the append mode. Then delete the file and try again. If you then get a zero length file there *must* be an exception: find it. If you get something else, tell us. The 'folder the .java files are in' is irrelevant. The folder you need write permission to is the current directory when you execute this code. Not necessarily the same thing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    try ( ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("employees.dat", true)); ) {
```

Change `true` to `false`, or remove it. You can't append to files created as object output streams, at least not like this, and it's debatable whether you're even supposed to be doing so.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < all.size(); i++) {
            if (all.get(i).getClass() == (new Secretary().getClass()))
                output.writeObject(new Secretary((Secretary) all.get(i)));
            else if (all.get(i).getClass() == (new Supervisor().getClass()))
                output.writeObject(new Supervisor((Supervisor) all.get(i)));
            else
                output.writeObject(new Employee(all.get(i)));
        }
```

Change this entire mess to this:

```
output.writeObject(all);
```

If this still doesn't work there must have been an exception somewhere, and you're just going to have to find it, print it, and post it. Edit it into your question. Or else you're looking at the wrong file.

NB you will also have to change the code that reads the file, to just read the list in a single `readObject()` call.

Answer (score 0):

By any chance are you happening to write an applet or JNLP without appropriate permissions?

do you have write access to the folder that you are outputting the file ? (which in this case is the directory that the program is running in. )

I would recomend calling io.printStackTrace() and se.printStackTrace(); in the exception handlers to provide significantly more information about the exceptions.

At the end of the file writing also dont forget to call output.close() to ensure that the stream is closed properly, the tail of the data is written and there are no left over open file handles on your system.

Comment: I changed the catch's like you suggested and re-tested.  No errors, but the file is still 0bytes (it should write 2 objects, an Employee and Supervisor).

I'm writing JavaFX.

Comment: it also appears that you forgot to call "close" on the stream

Comment: @DamianNikodem No, he is using try-with-resources; the close is automatic.

Comment: @EJP In which case it might be suggested that it be re-written as a normal try/catch block because there may be a exception during close.

Comment: @DamianNikodem A `flush()` inside the try block would be a better solution. That's the only thing that can cause `close()` to throw in practice.